# How to display totals row using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

is there a way to add sum of a column using VBA? I know I could use `'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"` to add the "Total" row, but I can't seem to find the way to add the sum of a column that I want. I tried using `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("queryName").Fields("Quantity").Properties("AggregateType").Value = 0` but nothing happened. I'd appreciate any help guys. By the way, here's my code.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim CustName As String
    Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef

    If IsNull(Combo2.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please Choose a customer"
    Else
        CustName = DLookup("[FullName]", "TblCustomer", _
                           "[CustID] = " & Combo2.Value)
        For Each qDef In db.QueryDefs
            If qDef.Name = "TblCustomer Query" Or qDef.Name = "TblLocationId Query" Then
            Else
                DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, qDef.Name
            End If
        Next

        Set qDef = db.CreateQueryDef(CustName)
        qDef.sQl = "SELECT OrderID, SaleDate, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Quantity * UnitPrice As TotalPrice FROM TblOrderDetails WHERE CustID = " & Combo2.Value & ""
        Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

        DoCmd.OpenQuery CustName, acViewNormal
        DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, CustName
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs(CustName).Fields("Quantity").Properties("AggregateType").Value = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you do this in form or report?

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA, not sure how to do that in report. Could you show me how to do that in report?

Comment: Use Sum() function in textbox in report footer: `=Sum([Quantity])`. No VBA. Instead of QueryDefs code, could just open report with filter criteria.

Comment: I don't think you need to use VBA to construct the query. You can make the query manually, including totals and a query parameter that takes its value from the selection textbox on your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using UNION in sql. Thanks for helping out guys!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but...
If you just want to display those built-in totals after opening the query, here's the solution:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery CustName, acViewNormal
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"
```