Invoke action of button with sigma sign on Records in the ribbon
In ACCESS  I use
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns

to invoke Hide and uhhide columns. How can I invoke aciton of button with sigma sign in group Records on the ribbon?
Which AcCommand constant should i use?
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmd????


Here's a list of options. It might not be available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.accommand - the only one with "Sum" in the name is acCmdPivotAutoSum

It doesn't show up in Intellisense with Access 2020 and I don't think it has anything to do with the Sigma tool. I expect it would have been associated with pivot objects which MS has removed from Access. Possibly those Pivot commands never were in Access and are Excel commands. Why toggle? If form is set for datasheet view, just design it with the Totals row set.

I found the answer here: How to display totals row using VBA? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582315/how-to-display-totals-row-using-vba
What I was looking for was: CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"
Thank You!
